# How to create tomcat access log setup?

Tags: apache, tomcat, logging

```
<Valve
    className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
    directory="${catalina.base}/logs"
    prefix="access_log"
    fileDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd.HH"
    suffix=".log"
    pattern="%t %H cookie:%{SESSIONID}c request:%{SESSIONID}r  %m %U %s %q      %r"
/>
```

But it is not working for me..No logs are being created. I want all the info of client including access time,IP, host,proxy IP,hostname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For time,IP, host,proxy IP,hostname - Check [link](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve) for reference. Use Following

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
```

logs are not created because of `directory="${catalina.base}/logs"`. Directory description is

> Absolute or relative pathname of a directory in which log files created by this valve will be placed. If a relative path is specified, it is interpreted as relative to $CATALINA_BASE. If no directory attribute is specified, the default value is "logs" (relative to $CATALINA_BASE).

You must specify only `directory="logs"`.

Comment: If I am not wrong, logs will be created in Tomcat/logs directory. right?Also I am using Ecliplse,will it be problem for creating log . Also if some permissions are need to be given? What I am missing here?

Comment: yes logs will be created in Tomcat/logs directory. In case of eclipse, log are located at  `YOUR_WORKSPACE_DIRECTORY\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\logs`